# Configuring .htaccess and retaining links from CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm working on this site:

http://www.snaprockandpop.co.uk

The site has just gone live (!) but there are some issues with the .htaccess file. It's a wordpress site and the content is hosted in a sub-domain (`wordpress.snaprockandpop.co.uk`) whose files are in a folder on the main domain i.e. `public-html/wordpress`

I'd like '`www.snaprockandpop.co.uk`' and '`snaprockandpop.co.uk`' to show the content hosted there without redirecting to the `wordpress.snaprockandpop.co.uk` URL, and for all content to be displayed from those URL's too

Following a guide I've edited the .htaccess file in the public-html root so it reads as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?snaprockandpop.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?snaprockandpop.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Before turning the site on I noted that this was working for the 'www' address but omitting the 'www' still redirected to 'wordpress.snaprockandpop.co.uk'. I figured I'd sort this out later as I just needed the site to be up. But, having switched it on the 'www' address has now dropped links to some custom fonts and icons. Plus, any page except the home page is served from the '`wordpress.snaprockandpop`' address.

Specifically an `@font-face` rule in the CSS has stopped working, despite being fine in the Wordpress backend previously. The links to the font files in the CSS are also absolute links i.e. `http://www.wordpress.snaprockandpop.co.uk/./././././myfont.TTF/OET/whatever` so I'm not sure why they would stop working.

For reference, this is the .htaccess file in the wordpress directory(`public-html/wordpress`):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any assistance here would be fantastic - as I said, site is live! :S